CVE-2024-38828 in Spring Framework: what's the root cause?
I heard about this vulnerability (CVE-2024-38828) and tried to seek for details, but couldn't find anything useful.
I could imagine why it may cause a DoS: sending too much data may cause a denial of service in the end. But what I don't understand, to properly think of implementing some countermeasures or a fix for this in my applications, is the technical explanation of the issue. Because if it's just a problem of "too much data", I am wondering if we can actually define this a "vulnerability".
Some questions come into my mind:

what does the fix in the commercially supported version 5.3.42 of the Spring Framework do? Does it simply disable the ability to use @RequestBody byte[]? Or rather implement some (configurable) limit check on the input size before processing? Or yet fix some other processing which was clearly wrong?
why @RequestBody String is not an issue instead? If the problem is just that the input might be so big to cause a DoS, couldn't a mapping to String suffer from the same problem?
why Spring Framework 6.x is not vulnerable?

I'm really curious about this, but could not find any explanation of the real problem anywhere.

I can imagine a fix already done for Spring 6 has been backported to Spring 5 after the CVE was reported. I don't really care about the details, the only proper way forward is to upgrade to Spring 6.

@Gimby I like to understand how things work and what to expect if I just upgrade to Spring 6 regarding this matter.

I really don't understand the downvotes. Am I supposed not to make questions just because a new version exists which apparently does not have this vulnerability?
